# How to pass multiple value as ID to `rvest`

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract a bunch of numbers from a website https://www.bcassessment.ca/ using `PID` (unique ID). The list of sample `PID` are shown below:

```
PID <- c("012-215-023", "024-521-647", "025-891-669")
```

For these values, I opened the website **manually** and in the **search engine** of the website, I chose **PID** from the list of available options and then searched these numbers. The search redirected me to the following URLs

```
URL <- c("https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwM1hIUA==",
         "https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwNEJKMA==",
         "https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMUc5OA==")
```

Then for each of these URLs, I ran the code shown below, to extract the total value of the property:

```
out <- c()
for (i in 1: length(URL)) {
  
  url <- URL[i]
  out[i] <- url %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes('span#lblTotalAssessedValue') %>%
    html_text()
  i <- i+1 
}
```

which gives me the final result

```
[1] "$543,000" "$957,000" "$487,000"
```

The problem is that I have a list of `PID` (more than 50000) and I cannot manually search each of these PIDs in the website to find the actual link and then run `rvest` to **scrape** it. How do you recommend automating this process so I can only provide PIDs and get the output price?

**Summary:** for a list of known `PID` I want to open https://www.bcassessment.ca/ and extract the most up-to-date price of the property, and I want it to be done Automatically.

**Test_PID**

I added list of `PID` code, so you can check if you want to check the code is working:

```
structure(list(P.I.D.. = c("004-050-541", "016-658-540", "016-657-861", 
"016-657-764", "019-048-386", "025-528-360", "800-058-036", "025-728-954", 
"028-445-783", "027-178-048", "028-445-571", "025-205-145", "015-752-798", 
"026-041-308", "024-521-698", "027-541-631", "024-360-651", "028-445-040", 
"025-851-411", "025-529-293", "024-138-436", "023-893-796", "018-496-768", 
"025-758-721", "024-219-665", "024-359-866", "018-511-015", "026-724-979", 
"023-894-253", "006-331-505", "025-961-012", "024-219-690", "027-309-878", 
"028-445-716", "025-759-060", "017-692-733", "025-728-237", "028-447-221", 
"023-894-202", "028-446-020", "026-827-611", "028-058-798", "017-574-412", 
"023-893-591", "018-511-457", "025-960-199", "027-178-714", "027-674-941", 
"027-874-826", "025-110-390", "028-071-336", "018-257-984", "023-923-393", 
"026-367-203", "027-601-854", "003-773-922", "025-902-989", "018-060-641", 
"025-530-003", "018-060-722", "025-960-423", "016-160-126", "009-301-461", 
"025-960-580", "019-090-315", "023-464-283", "028-445-503", "006-395-708", 
"028-446-674", "018-258-549", "023-247-398", "029-321-166", "024-519-871", 
"023-154-161", "003-904-547", "004-640-357", "006-314-864", "025-960-521", 
"013-326-783", "003-430-049", "027-490-084", "024-360-392", "028-054-474", 
"026-076-179", "005-309-689", "024-613-509", "025-978-551", "012-215-066", 
"024-034-002", "025-847-244", "024-222-038", "003-912-019", "024-845-264", 
"006-186-254", "026-826-691", "026-826-712", "024-575-569", "028-572-581", 
"026-197-774", "009-695-958", "016-089-120", "025-703-811", "024-576-671", 
"026-460-751", "026-460-149", "003-794-181", "018-378-684", "023-916-745", 
"003-497-721", "003-397-599", "024-982-211", "018-060-129", "018-061-231", 
"017-765-714", "027-303-799", "028-565-312", "018-061-010", "006-338-232", 
"023-680-024", "028-983-971", "028-092-490", "006-293-239", "018-061-257", 
"028-092-376", "018-060-137", "004-302-664", "016-988-060", "003-371-166", 
"027-325-342", "011-475-480", "018-060-200")), row.names = c(NA, 
-131L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

P.S. The website I mentioned is a public website and everyone can open it and add an address to find the estimated price of a property, so I don't think there is any problem with scraping it as it's a public database.

Comment: I'd recommend RSelenium or did you look into that already?

Comment: @Taufi, No I don't know much about it. Is it a package for scraping? any good resources on that?

Comment: A quick Google search will turn up a lot of material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the pid through the form, it triggers the following call:

```
GET https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Search/GetByPid/012215023?PID=012215023&_=1619713418473
```

The call above has the following parameters:

- `012215023` is the PID without dash `-` in your input. It's both a path and query parameter
- `1619713418473` is the current timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 (unix timestamp)

The result of the call above is a json response like this:

```json
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "aaData": [
        ["XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXX", "200-027-615-115-48-0004", "QTAwMDAwM1hIUA=="]
    ]
}
```

The above call returns the response as `text/plain` and not as `application/json` content type, so we have to parse it using `jsonlite`. Then pick the last item of `aaData` array value which is, in this case: `QTAwMDAwM1hIUA==` and build the resulted url like the one in your post.

The following code gets a list of PID and extracts the $ values for each one of these:

```
library(rvest)

getValueForPID <- function(pid) {
  pidNum = gsub("-", "", pid)

  time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))*1000

  output <- content(httr::GET(paste0("https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Search/GetByPid/",pidNum), query = list(
    "PID" = pidNum,
    "_" = format(time, digits=13)
  )), "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

  if(output == "found_no_results"){
    return("")
  }
  data = jsonlite::fromJSON(output)

  id = data$aaData[5]

  text <- paste0("https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Info/", id) %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes('span#lblTotalAssessedValue') %>%
    html_text()

  return(text)
}

PID <- c("004-050-541", "016-658-540", "016-657-861", "016-657-764", "019-048-386", "025-528-360", "800-058-036")

out <- c()
count <- 1
for (i in PID) {
  print(i)
  out[count] <- getValueForPID(i)
  count <- count + 1
}
print(out)
```

sample output:

```
[1] "$543,000" "$957,000" "$487,000"
```

kaggle link: https://www.kaggle.com/bertrandmartel/bcassesment-pid

Comment: Thanks, @Bertrand for your clear solution. I just have a couple of questions to make sure I understand this correctly. The first question is that how do you know that when we search an ID, it triggers `GET https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Search/GetByPid/012215023?PID=012215023&_=1619713418473` ? is it something fundamental that I should know from html or you found this by inspecting the html code behind the website?

Comment: The second question is pretty much the same as the first question and it's about `Json` file, how do you know the expected output would be in form of `{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "aaData": [
        ["XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXX", "200-027-615-115-48-0004", "QTAwMDAwM1hIUA=="]
    ]
}`

Comment: And the third question is what does ` time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))*1000` do in your code? how does this timestamp affect the result?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you You can see the request by opening chrome development console / network tab. After clicking the search button I‘ve clicked on this get call and you can right click/ copy as curl then The result was the json depicted above.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have difficulties in finding what you explained. Do mind taking a picture of what you are suggesting and include it in your solution? so I have a better understanding of it?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KiyK.png), [copy as curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU2Mc.png) and [the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjdT.png)

Comment: @Roozbeh_you `how does this timestamp affect the result`, it's present in the original request so I've included it, it may or may not affect the result but it's safer to include it in case it's checked server side

Comment: Thanks so much, @Bertrand Martel. I think you clearly helped me with your solution. I accepted your answer